# Assigning values to child controller within ng-repeat using controllerAs.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was reading this [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers) about using the `controllerAs` syntax and avoiding the use of `$scope` when possible.

I have a `UsersController` that has an array of `users`. I then use a `ng-repeat` directive with a nested `UserController`.

My problem is, I don't know how I should access (or assign) the `user` value to my `UserController` without the use of `$scope`. Any suggestions? Here is [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5XeihZ5wtt2VIQjteFg?p=preview).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersController as usersCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="user in usersCtrl.users">
    <div ng-controller="UserController as userCtrl">
      <ul>

        <!-- How can I access user from UserController without using $scope? -->
        <li>{{user.index}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in user.friends">{{friend.name}}</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The javascript:

```
/* UserController */

function UserController($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  /* How to access/assign 'user' without using $scope? 

    Is there a better way than the following?
    vm.user = $scope.user

   */

}

/* UsersController */
function UsersController(dataService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.users = dataService;

}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with `user` inside the `UserController`.  If you want to call a function, for example, you can always just pass the `user`:  `vm.doSomething(user) { // use the user }`

Comment: The internet contain a lot of false, old and bad practices code examples.

Comment: @DavinTryon, Yea, `user` is a `$resource`, so my idea was to do something like `user.addFriend(friendName);`, something along those lines - where `friendName` would be passed from the html.

Comment: @Linial, According to the [ngController documentation from AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) - in the examples section it mentions the advantages of using the `controllerAs` syntax. I'm not saying one is better than the other, I'm just trying out both approaches.

Comment: Funny enough those two approaches, do literally the same thing! referring to this in your function scope, is exactly the same as calling the $scope in your controller. I would really suggest you follow the most readable way, the only advantage that `ControllerAs` has to offer is the possibility to minify your code completely without breaking it.